# C delete files and directories, recursively if directory

Tags: c, recursion, file-system

This is my function that uses recursion to recursively delete a directory. I like my way of skipping entries `.` and `..`.

But should I be casting the name lengths to `unsigned int` because I am quite sure there will not be file paths longer than 4 gigacharacters? Or is storing the result of `strlen` in any type other than `size_t` bad practice?

Any other comments here?

Also is using VLAs in a recursive function risky, could it cause a stack overflow error? Is the VLA OK, or should I just use `malloc()` (I vehemently refuse to simply use a fixed size buffer that *should* be big enough, like <s>`char Entry[1024]`</s>)?

```
int Remove(const char *const Object) {
    DIR *const Dir = opendir(Object);
    if (Dir) {
        struct dirent *Dirent;
        const unsigned int Len = (unsigned int)strlen(Object);
        while ((Dirent = readdir(Dir))) {
            const char *const Name = Dirent->d_name;
            const unsigned int NameLen = (unsigned int)strlen(Name);
            if (Name[0] == '.' && (NameLen == 1 || (Name[1] == '.' && NameLen == 2))) {
                continue;
            }
            char Entry[Len+NameLen+2], *const CurrPtr = memcpy(Entry, Object, Len)+Len;
            *CurrPtr = '/';
            *(char *)(memcpy(CurrPtr+1, Name, NameLen)+NameLen) = 0;
            if ((Dirent->d_type == DT_DIR? Remove : remove)(Entry)) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        if (closedir(Dir)) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return remove(Object);
}
```

Comment: Note that `d_type` is an optional optimization, and can be DT_UNKNOWN.  See [Checking if a dir. entry returned by readdir is a directory, link or file. dent->d\_type isn't showing the type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23958040)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/6441osr7G includes the necessary headers.  Looks like it compiles efficiently, with GCC deallocating the VLA at the end of every inner loop.

Answer (score 5):

We're missing the necessary headers for `struct dirent` and the Standard library string functions (`strlen`, `memcpy` etc).

It's probably worth providing an explanatory comment that tells the user what the return values mean.  It appears that it returns 0 on success, or -1 with `errno` set to a suitable value if it fails.

I don't think it's a great idea to use a name that differs only in case from the Standard Library function `remove()`.  Call it `remove_recursively()` or something instead.

> ```
>         const unsigned int Len = (unsigned int)strlen(Object);
>         const unsigned int NameLen = (unsigned int)strlen(Name);
> ```

Why the cast?  We should just keep them as `size_t`.

I'm not a fan of the cutesy

> ```
>         *(char *)(memcpy(CurrPtr+1, Name, NameLen)+NameLen) = 0;
> ```

To be correct, we need to convert the return value of `memcpy()` to `char*` *before* adding `NameLen`:

```
        *((char *)memcpy(CurrPtr+1, Name, NameLen)+NameLen) = 0;
```

But honestly, I'd avoid the casting entirely and write as a pair of much more readable lines:

```
        memcpy(CurrPtr+1, Name, NameLen);
        CurrPtr[NameLen+1] = '\0';
```

Or simpler still, get rid of the manual concatenation and let the library do it for us:

```
        sprintf(Entry, "%s/%s", Object, Name);
```

> ```
>        if ((Dirent->d_type == DT_DIR? Remove : remove)(Entry)) {
> ```

<s>The conditional operator is unnecessary - just call our `Remove()`, which will get a null return from `opendir()` and then simply unlink the file.</s>  Actually, the test is a good idea, as it prevents us following symlinks.

> ```
>         if ((Dirent->d_type == DT_DIR? Remove : remove)(Entry)) {
>             return -1;
>         }
> ```

Oops - we forgot to `closedir()` before returning, meaning that we leak a descriptor for every level of recursion.

> ```
>     if (closedir(directory)) {
>         return -1;
>     }
> ```

This check may be overkill - the only documented failure possibility is `EBADF` if we pass a directory that's e.g. already closed.  We know the full history of the descriptor, so that can never happen.

---

## Simplified version

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int remove_recursive(const char *const path) {
    DIR *const directory = opendir(path);
    if (directory) {
        struct dirent *entry;
        while ((entry = readdir(directory))) {
            if (!strcmp(".", entry->d_name) || !strcmp("..", entry->d_name)) {
                continue;
            }
            char filename[strlen(path) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 2];
            sprintf(filename, "%s/%s", path, entry->d_name);
            int (*const remove_func)(const char*) = entry->d_type == DT_DIR ? remove_recursive : remove;
            if (remove_func(entry->d_name)) {
                closedir(directory);
                return -1;
            }
        }
        if (closedir(directory)) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return remove(path);
}
```

Comment: The question (and your update) don't handle filesystems where d_type == DT_UNKNOWN.  See [Checking if a dir. entry returned by readdir is a directory, link or file. dent->d\_type isn't showing the type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23958040)

Comment: The reason I manually concatenate the string myself, is because I treat `strlen` to be a relatively expensive operation, and `sprintf` internally calls `strlen`. Also I get the length of the path outside of the loop because it will never change inside the loop. As for the return value of `closedir()` how does an `assert` sound?

Comment: @user244272 It is possible that, when deleting directories, the time taken by disk operations will entirely dwarf the time taken by string operations.  If you still feel this optimization is needed, measurement to back up that feeling could be useful.

Comment: @user244272: I'd `perror` a warning on `closedir(2)` errors, but otherwise just continue.  At worst it means you leak an FD.  I don't think that can lead to a case where your program erroneously recurses into the wrong tree and deletes more than it should (like this buggy build script that used dead-reckoning `cd ../foo/bar` into stuff and `cd ../../..` back out, all without error checking: [I just deleted everything in my home directory. How? And why are some files still there?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/649408))

Comment: @WayneConrad: System calls might pollute data and instruction caches, making bulky over-complicated code between calls even slower.  sprintf has a pretty large code footprint.  To be fair, path strings are never going to be huge, and strlen is pretty fast on modern systems, though, and system call overhead on modern CPUs (especially Intel with Spectre mitigation) is pretty big even compared to a few cache misses.  Remember that modern OSes don't wait for the data to be updated on disk before `unlink` returns, though, so it's just updating metadata for eventual write-back of a batch of deletes.

Comment: @WayneConrad: But fortunately POSIX 2008 `unlinkat(2)` lets you use paths relative to an open directory FD, so you don't need any string manipulation.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not arguing against optimization.  Just against doing it before measurement shows there's a problem.

Comment: I am also not arguing against this answer, which I think is good.

Comment: @WayneConrad: Yeah, but when it's possible to write obviously more efficient code without hurting human readability or robustness, that's always better.  I dislike the idea of leaving obviously-slow code around just because the current speed is good enough for now.  Especially when the difference is in cache footprint, the cost it imposes isn't fully visible in microbenchmarks, just in cache misses spread around the rest of the program.  In this case the simplicity of sprintf might be worth it (although some of that goes out the window with buffer length checking).

Comment: (My other point is that *if* you know a lot about how performance, and how CPUs and compilers work, you can make some reasonable estimates without having to measure every time.  Microbenchmarking accurately is hard.)

Comment: @Peter, I'd completely forgotten that some filesystems return `DT_UNKNOWN`.  Would you care to write an answer with that observation?  I think it deserves more than just a comment here.

Comment: @user244272, why do you think `sprintf()` would call `strlen`?  That part is just like `strcpy()` - just keep going until you see `\0`.  I would code for clarity and maintainability here anyway - there's no point micro-optimising code that's dwarfed by filesystem access.  I considered recommending `assert(closedir(…) == 0)` - if it fails it's definitely a programming error you want your debug builds to diagnose.

Answer (score 4):

It might be possible to avoid copying the filenames, if it's okay for the function to change the working directory.  We can `chdir` into the directory to be removed, remove all its content (using the relative names directly from the `dirent` structure), then change back when we're done.  That keeps the per-frame overhead absolutely minimal.

Actually we can avoid changing working directory if we're on a platform that provides [`unlinkat()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) (thanks to Peter Cordes for suggesting this).  The code then looks very simple:

```
        int unlinkflags = entry->d_type == DT_DIR ? AT_REMOVEDIR : 0;
        if (unlinkat(dirfd(directory), entry->d_name, unlinkflags)) {
            closedir(directory);
            return -1;
        }
```

Comment: Or since this is already using `readdir`, use other POSIX functions like `unlinkat(dirfd, path, flags)` to allow using paths relative to a directory (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html).  (Instead of using ISO C stdio.h `remove(3)`.)

Comment: Ah yes, I'd totally forgotten about `unlinkat()` - that's much better than modifying the process working directory.  Answer updated, and thank you again!